# Why feedparser for Python does not see all elements in the feed

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I use the following code:

```
import feedparser as fp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://www.careerbuilder.de/RTQ/rss20.aspx?rssid=RSS_PD&num=25&geoip=false&ddcompany=false&ddtitle=false&cat=JN038'  
    d = fp.parse(url)
    for entry in d.entries:
        print entry
        print '----------------------'
```

As a result I get:

```
{'guidislink': 0, 'published': u'Wed, 23 Apr 2014 04:00:00 Z', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=4, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=113, tm_isdst=0), 'title': u'Bankkaufmann (m/w)'}
----------------------
{'guidislink': 0, 'published': u'Wed, 23 Apr 2014 04:00:00 Z', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=4, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=113, tm_isdst=0), 'title': u'Anlagenbuchhalter (m/w)'}
----------------------
{'guidislink': 0, 'published': u'Wed, 23 Apr 2014 04:00:00 Z', 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=23, tm_hour=4, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=113, tm_isdst=0), 'title': u'Bankkaufleute (m/w)'}
----------------------
```

It looks like entries in the feed do not have "summary" and "link" elements. As a conformation of that, I get an error message if I try to use `entry.summary` or `entry.description`. This is strange to me since I do see `link` and `description` elements in the xml for the feed, if I open it in my browser.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [revision history of feedparser](http://universal-feedparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#revision-history):

> Universal Feed Parser 3.0b18 was released on February 17, 2004.
>
> - always map description to summary_detail (Andrei)
> - use libxml2 (if available)

And from [here](http://universal-feedparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#entries-i-link)

> Some RSS feeds use guid when they mean link. guid can also be used as
>   an opaque identifier that has nothing to do with links. If an RSS feed
>   uses guid as the entry link and no link is present, Universal Feed
>   Parser detects this and makes the guid available in `d.entries[i].link`.

Maybe that's why I can access `entry.link` and `entry.description` without any error, though `print entry.keys()` gives

```
['summary_detail', 'published_parsed', 'links', 'title', 'summary', 'guidislink', 'title_detail', 'link', 'published', 'id']
```